# Laravel Forge Commit Issue - on Composer Change

Tags: php, git, laravel, forge, laravel-forge

I am using Laravel with Forge and Digital Ocean.

When I make changes and deploy all works fine, until I add a new package with Composer, I get the below error and It will not deploy after this point?

```
Wed Jun 15 12:03:12 BST 2016
Warning: Permanently added the RSA host key for IP address '192.30.252.120' to the list of known hosts.
From github.com:********/****
 * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
   08f475b..5802179  master     -> origin/master
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:
    vendor/composer/autoload_classmap.php
    vendor/composer/autoload_namespaces.php
    vendor/composer/installed.json
Please, commit your changes or stash them before you can merge.
Aborting
Updating e20816a..5802179
```

The only way that I can fix is to delete the server and restart. I am using sourcetree to push changes to Git.

Comment: Remove the `/vendor` directory out of your git repo and as part of your deploy process run `composer install`

Answer (score 0):

SSH into the server, cd into the directory and the

```
git reset --hard <Latest Commit>
```

In digital ocean, when you log in, there is a command line utility that you can open and use as you would a normal terminal.

Forge would have emailed you your details to log in using that

Comment: Thanks for the help, this didn't work however I still get the same message.

Answer (score 0):

Just ssh into the server and do `git checkout .` ( Don't forget the dot (.) ). And also make sure if your vendor folder is in **git ignore** or not. This might have happened when composer have tried to update while deploying the changes to the server and your vendor folder is not in .gitignore. Try this hope it helps you.

Comment: What is git checkout .

Comment: It reverts changes that are not committed @MitchellYuen